Should I be using a lower resolution in my LMM if it dosen't match my predictor variables?
I have a set of animal movement values which are sampled at three hours (e.g. 500m/3h)
I ran a Linear mixed model with the movement distance as the response variable, using sex, daytime (night and day) and month as explainables but now I am reconsidering.
Since the lowest resolution of my predictor covariates is for daytime(~12h) I am reconsidering whether it is better to run my model with a) the three hour values, b) with the average of those for every night/day or c) with the sum of those for every day/night.
From a research point of view any one of these serve the same point for my research question,But I am not so sure about the statistics part of it. I am having trouble rationalizing any one choice to myself.

If your predictor covariates is for daytime(~12h)then your three-hour movement values can bring some noise or autocorrelation because the predictors won't explain variability at that finer resolution. And this mismatch in 3h resolution can reduce the model's ability to detect important patterns.
I recommend you b choice: to AVG per day and night and it will smooth out fluctuations and reduce the noise. Also sum of those for every day/night period will transform variable to cumulative and it will be easy to explain in some cases.
Statistically short time period movement are more likely correlated and it will pump up your Type1 error. Aggregating or summarizing will reduce risk of autocorrelation and make more simple relationship between predictors and responds, bring more balance in your model.
